# parsing a website not getting title using document.getElementsByClassName() flutter

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, flutter-web

I am parsing a website (AliBabaExpress). I need to get title of a product.
 I am using document.getElementsByClassName("product-title").
When i go to that url 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000393031102.html?spm=a2g0o.home.15002.1.650c2145Nb81Vg&gps-id=pcJustForYou&scm=1007.13562.168240.0&scm_id=1007.13562.168240.0&scm-url=1007.13562.168240.0&pvid=5f921182-14c0-4c6a-ac6d-b4620a2904c5&_t=gps-id:pcJustForYou,scm-url:1007.13562.168240.0,pvid:5f921182-14c0-4c6a-ac6d-b4620a2904c5,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%2318_668%23808%234093%2347_668%23888%233325%239_668%232846%238110%23375_668%232717%237566%23899' 
What i need is to get title of that particular item. The code i am using is:
[image: In image you can see the highlighted text and i also inspect that element that i need]

```
 var menu = null;
 try {
  print('see url');
  print(url);
  print('see url');

  if (url == null || url == "")
    return false;
  menu = await http.get(url);
  this.url = url;
  print('response is: ${menu.body}');
  var document = parse(menu.body);
 var titleTag = document.getElementsByClassName("product-title");

    print('Title is : $titleTag');

    title = titleTag[0].attributes['h1'];
    print('Title is: $title');
   }catch(e){
       print(e);}
```

**Note: I just want to print the name i have pasted the link of url and image as well from which i want to take title.**

Comment: The classname in that picture says product-title-text so you'd also need to do `document.getElementsByClassName("product-title-text");`

Comment: Not working suggest me another solution

Comment: Are you using HTMLElementView widget with Iframe..?

Comment: I am using `import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart';`